# How does IIS identifies that it needs to serve aspx/php/html page?

Tags: .net, asp.net, visual-studio, iis

I wonder, if a user request an ASP.NET Page (with .aspx) extension, how does IIS identifies that it needs to server .aspx/.php/.html or any other page?

OR

When a first request is sent out from client's web browser, what happens at back end, till the web page is served at the client's end?

Let me know if any query/doubt

Thanks (in advance)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File extensions are mapped to ISAPI filters.

http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/ad520e25-877c-4764-bfe5-a9d5a9a5d3bb.mspx?mfr=true

When a request for a certain mapping is received, IIS essentially defers the processing to the given ISAPI filter. This is very similar to the Fast CGI process used by Apache.

Answer (score 2):

IIS uses [handlers](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771240.aspx) to process non-html content.  Handlers are mapped using the extension of the file being requested (i.e. aspnet_isapi.dll for aspx/asmx/etc).

Answer (score 1):

Right click on Website -goto properties->Vetrualdirectory->Application Mapping->click Configuration.. button->under applicationmapping you will find all isapi with file name extension ex:aspx-aspnet_isapi used to serve the page. You could also try by changing the name of file extension and map the file extension with any isapi extension

regards
radhe shyam